# Google DFP ads don't always display

Tags: google-dfp

I'm using Google DFP to display ads on several Joomla web sites. Periodically, a page will load and none of the ads will display. Refreshing the page will get the ads back. It doesn't always happen and I have not found a way to replicate the issue. Some times it happens clicking around on a site, other times when loading a URL directly.

The only constant is that when the problem occurs, none of the ads on the page will display and refreshing the page always makes the ads display.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console when it happens?

Comment: Nope. There are no errors in the console. Refreshing the page fixes the problem every time.